# how to render a unidimensional and multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, arraylist

I am rendering a multidimensional array obtained by a WS, it works perfectly but when changing the structure of the array to multidimensional it shows me an error when rendering. This is my array:

```
array(5) { ["@attributes"]=> array(1) { ["id"]=> string(13) "08" } ["nom-afi"]=> string(23) "Perez Pedro" ["PRESTAMO"]=> array(2) { [0]=> array(11) { ["num-pr"]=> string(14) "76" ["fec-dsb"]=> string(8) "20180503" ["fec-vnc"]=> string(8) "20230522" ["mto-otor"]=> string(5) "55400" ["plazo"]=> string(20) "60 MESES (60 CUOTAS)" ["tasa"]=> string(1) "0" ["cta-pgadas"]=> string(1) "3" ["cta-mora"]=> string(1) "0" ["sdo-vnc"]=> string(1) "0" ["sdo-actual"]=> string(7) "54382.9" ["cuota-niv"]=> string(7) "1177.09" } [1]=> array(11) { ["num-pr"]=> string(14) "061" ["fec-dsb"]=> string(8) "20180409" ["fec-vnc"]=> string(8) "20230522" ["mto-otor"]=> string(9) "116309.24" ["plazo"]=> string(20) "60 MESES (60 CUOTAS)" ["tasa"]=> string(1) "0" ["cta-pgadas"]=> string(1) "3" ["cta-mora"]=> string(1) "0" ["sdo-vnc"]=> string(1) "0" ["sdo-actual"]=> string(9) "114173.92" ["cuota-niv"]=> string(7) "2471.23" } } }
```

this is how I render

```
 <?php foreach($PRESTAMOS_LISTADO['PRESTAMO'] as $result): ?>

<option value="<?php echo $result['num-pr']; ?>"><?php echo $result['num-pr']; ?></option>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

up to this point it works quite well, until I render this other array:

```
array(5) { ["@attributes"]=> array(1) { ["id"]=> string(13) "17" } ["nom-afi"]=> string(23) "ALBA" ["PRESTAMO"]=> array(11) { ["num-pr"]=> string(14) "28" ["fec-dsb"]=> string(8) "20180214" ["fec-vnc"]=> string(8) "20190927" ["mto-otor"]=> string(5) "15000" ["plazo"]=> string(20) "18 MESES (18 CUOTAS)" ["tasa"]=> string(1) "0" ["cta-pgadas"]=> string(1) "6" ["cta-mora"]=> string(1) "0" ["sdo-vnc"]=> string(1) "0" ["sdo-actual"]=> string(8) "11058.57" ["cuota-niv"]=> string(6) "900.86" } }
```

this gave me the next code error:

```
Warning: Illegal string offset 'num-pr' in C:\xampp\htdocs\proyect\assets\WSHelper.php on line 90
```

How could I render and apply for multidimensional and unidimensional arrays? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this to check if `$PRESTAMOS_LISTADO['PRESTAMO']` is a simple result array and if so, convert it into an array of 1 result:

```
if (isset($PRESTAMOS_LISTADO['PRESTAMO']['num-pr'])) {
    $results = array($PRESTAMOS_LISTADO['PRESTAMO']);
}
else {
    $results = $PRESTAMOS_LISTADO['PRESTAMO'];
}
```

Then you can use `$results` in your `foreach`:

```
<?php foreach ($results as $result): ?>
```